# Elasticsearch search array inside elastic object

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am working on elastic search in node.js. I have 50k+ users in elstic search and now I have an of of phone numbers. Now I want to get those users from elastic search who match these number in array for this purpose I write search query string but this query give me exception I don't know where I am doing mistake in my query string.

**Query String**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { 
          "prefix": {
              "phone":{"+9665509548","+93565822145",...}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without knowing your index mapping and the actual error message, so please provide those.

Comment: On top of that, your query simply isn't valid JSON. You need to have a `{"phone": "value"}` dict object under prefix

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { 
          "prefix": {
              "phone": "+9665509548"
          }
        },
        { 
          "prefix": {
              "phone": "+93565822145"
          }
        },
        //...
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```